Monte-Carlo Simulation - approx 20 Stocks with Correlation
Believe it or not, but I studied quant finance probably 20 years ago and I haven't put my knowledge to good use in a while, so I'm a little rusty.
I need to run a Monte-Carlo simulation on a share price to value performance share units which have 0-200% performance factor based on relative share price performance vs. ~20 or so peers.
Looking at my old textbooks, I see very little examples on how to incorporate correlation between returns.
Can someone validate my approach and also give me a few pointers as to what should I look at to make sure my numerical implementation in Octave is good?
Approach to generate price paths

Compute daily log returns for each company (last 252 days)
Compute std and mean (calibrated on last 252 trading days)
Compute correlation matrix of daily log returns matrix
Create matrix of volatility/correlation
Generate matrix of random numbers, multiplied by cholesky decomposition of the matrix generated in step 4
Generate price path for each company via GBM

How would I go about validating my results are good?
How do I compare for example, the mean and std deviation of the end prices for one company with a theoretical solution?
Thank you
--
## Clear Workspace
clear

## Import Data (Daily Price Data - Newest (top) to Oldest) - Last 252 trading years
PriceData = dlmread ('PriceData.csv',',')

# Projections over 1.25 years
Numberofdays = 252*1.25;

PriceDataLogReturns = log(PriceData(1:end-1,:)./PriceData(2:end,:));
GBMParameters(1,:)=std(PriceDataLogReturns);
GBMParameters(2,:)=mean(PriceDataLogReturns);
InitialPrices = PriceData(:,end)

#Generate Correlation Matrix From Log Returns
CorrelMatrix = corr(PriceDataLogReturns);

#Create volatility matrix
Sigma = zeros(19,19);
for NbPeers = 1:1:19
   for NbPeers2 = 1:1:19
      if NbPeers==NbPeers2
      Sigma(NbPeers,NbPeers2) = GBMParameters(1,NbPeers)^2;
      else
      Sigma(NbPeers,NbPeers2) = GBMParameters(1,NbPeers)*GBMParameters(1,NbPeers2)*CorrelMatrix(NbPeers,NbPeers2);
      end
   end
end

C=chol(Sigma);

for MC = 1:1:1000
B = randn(19,Numberofdays);
V = C'*B;
Prices = zeros(Numberofdays +1,19);
Prices(1,:) = PriceData(1,:);
for i = 2:1:Numberofdays +1
  for NbPeers = 1:1:19 #Should be 19 // Set to 1 if only pulling for ATRL
Prices(i,NbPeers) = Prices(i-1,NbPeers)*exp((GBMParameters(2,NbPeers) - (0.5*GBMParameters(1,NbPeers)^2))*1 +sqrt(1)*V(NbPeers,i-1));
end

end

EndPrices(:,MC) = Prices(end,:)';
end

PSUReturns = (EndPrices./InitialPrices' - 1)*100;


Monte Carlo simulation (MCS), as you probably already know, can be used for simulating spot price evolutions with a drift and random component to deduce option prices.
My personal opinion as to how to validate the mean and SD of your prices is - try to apply MCS to price an option on that underlying asset, and make sure the price of that option coincides with the Black-Scholes price, which should have some common variables with the MCS simulation. At the very least, if the two prices converge, you would know the mechanics of your MCS is working correctly.
If you are asking about an economical type of validation, I don't have one.

Hi and thanks - yes, good idea if you're working on on a single security. In my case,I want to validate the results of my MC simulation that is impacted by the correlation with other securities.

I didn't read your code but including correlation in MCS by linking the Wiener processes is quite simple, I don't think that needs a validation?

@Dibbs on second thought, it might be a good idea to see if the correlation specified between the Wiener processes matches the historical correlation estimated in your correlation matrix. I think this is works well as a validation.

Good idea - i'll run a correlation matrix on log returns from projected stock prices

Good luck! Feel free to give me an upvote or tick as the solution if you feel my answer helped, thanks.
